# Confirm the existence of directory under the home directory

Tags: shell, directory, quoting

I would like to check the existence of directory and write the script below, but this doesn't work properly.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -d "~/sample" ]
then
    echo 'exists'
else
    echo 'NOT exists'
fi
```

Scripts below can work.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -d "/home/user01/sample" ]
then
    echo 'exists'
else
    echo 'NOT exists'
fi
```

`if [ -d "~/sample" ]` is something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the double quotes are what is not letting the ~ expand... the following will work:

```
if [ -d ~"/sample" ]; then
   echo "exists"
fi
```

It is usually better to use:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/sample" ] ; then
   echo "exists"
fi
```

$HOME is typically set by Bourne shells